# how to muliselect[at least two adjacent] items without manually pressing ctrl key and sort them with the rest of the items list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-ui-sortable

well iam working on sortable angular ui-sortable plugin
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

my goal :-muliselect item and sort them simultaneously.

well that can be done with muliselect library of this plugin but for that we have to manually first press and hold  ctrl key and while selecting  multiple item then release ctrl key now you can sort multiple items.
https://github.com/thgreasi/ui-sortable-multiselection

but i dont want user to manually press and hold ctrl key.

currently iam thinking i will trigger ctrl press key for some time and will trigger click on next item then sort the list.
  i wasted lots of time on this idea but not seems  working.am i doing it wrong?

## Json data:-

var array = [

{
'item':1,
'superset':'true'
},
{
'item':2,
'superset':'false'
},
{
'item':3,
'superset':'true'
},
{
'item':4,
'superset':'false'
},
{
'item':5,
'superset':'true'
},
{
'item':6,
'superset':'false'},
{
'item':7,
'superset':'true'
},
{
'item':8,
'superset':'false'
},
{
'item':9,
'superset':'true'

},
{

'item':10,
'superset':'false'}

];

inside angular ng-repeat if i found superset key ==true for any item then i want its next adjacent item to be moved with it which  have superset ==true.

Comment: You mean technically not working or practically/UX wise? Show some code. Holding Ctrl is good practice to provide consistency with other apps.

Comment: @JoelHarkes i have added some json data .hope you will undestand.

Comment: and i cannot let user to first hold ctrl key because its bonding should be automatic based on json key as i discussed above. if i found in any item superset key ==true it should move with immediately next item to it.

Comment: Are you sure your json data will always contains items with superset true and false alternatively? What if there are two consecutive items with superset true?

Comment: well in the staring i will not have any flag with superset inside json. once data get rendered with ng-repeat  inside html view .after that on clicking of any item i have some functionality which will add superset flag to that item and will update that josn in the db.so  now if i move any item if that item has superset flag ==true than next item to it should also move with it.  @NiK648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement your requirements with the plugins that you are using. But I couldn't get it to work. But I managed to get it working with this plugin: [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists).
It has a multiselection feature that was relatively easy to implement.
I copied the code from the multiselection demo([here](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/multi)) in their page and modified it according to your requirements.
Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fq4ca0LlKbsfLtFifQ2s?p=preview.
Code:
HTML

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul dnd-list dnd-drop="onDrop(model, val, index)">
      <li ng-repeat="val in model.items"
      dnd-draggable="getSelectedItemsIncluding(model, val)"
      dnd-dragstart="onDragstart(model, event)"
      dnd-moved="onMoved(model)"
      dnd-dragend="model.dragging = false"
      dnd-selected="val.selected = !val.selected"
      ng-class="{'selected': val.selected}"
      ng-hide="model.dragging && val.selected"
      ng-init="val.selected=false">
        {{ "Item " + val.item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['dndLists']);

myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    items: [{
      'item': 1,
      'superset': true
    }, {
      'item': 2,
      'superset': false
    }, {
      'item': 3,
      'superset': true
    }, {
      'item': 4,
      'superset': false
    }, {
      'item': 5,
      'superset': true
    }, {
      'item': 6,
      'superset': false
    }, {
      'item': 7,
      'superset': true
    }, {
      'item': 8,
      'superset': false
    }, {
      'item': 9,
      'superset': true
    }, {
      'item': 10,
      'superset': false
    }],
    dragging: false
  };

  /**
   * dnd-dragging determines what data gets serialized and send to the receiver
   * of the drop. While we usually just send a single object, we send the array
   * of all selected items here.
   */
  $scope.getSelectedItemsIncluding = function(list, item) {
    item.selected = true;
    if(item.superset) {
      var index = list.items.indexOf(item);
      list.items[index+1].selected = true;
    }
    return list.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.selected;
    });
  };

  /**
   * We set the list into dragging state, meaning the items that are being
   * dragged are hidden. We also use the HTML5 API directly to set a custom
   * image, since otherwise only the one item that the user actually dragged
   * would be shown as drag image.
   */
  $scope.onDragstart = function(list, event) {
    list.dragging = true;
    console.log(event);
    if (event.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {

      //event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
  };

  /**
   * In the dnd-drop callback, we now have to handle the data array that we
   * sent above. We handle the insertion into the list ourselves. By returning
   * true, the dnd-list directive won't do the insertion itself.
   */
  $scope.onDrop = function(list, items, index) {
    items = list.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.selected;
    });
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      item.selected = false;
      list.items.splice(list.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    });
    index = index - items.length;
    list.items = list.items.slice(0, index)
      .concat(items)
      .concat(list.items.slice(index));
      $scope.$apply();
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Last but not least, we have to remove the previously dragged items in the
   * dnd-moved callback.
   */
  $scope.onMoved = function(list) {
    list.items = list.items.filter(function(item) {
      return !item.selected;
    });
  };

});
```

CSS

```
/**
 * The dnd-list should always have a min-height,
 * otherwise you can't drop into it once it's empty
 */
.multiDemo ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

/**
 * An element with .dndPlaceholder class will be
 * added to the dnd-list while the user is dragging
 * over it.
 */
.multiDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 42px;
}

.multiDemo ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

/**
 * Show selected elements in green
 */
.multiDemo ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome. If it helped you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: i think i dont have that privilege for now

Comment: your solution working fine if  i drag from top to bottom  but when i move item  from bottom to top then  if i want to put item after 4th element say it get dropped on before 4th item  of intended item